# My PC Blue Screened and won't restart (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, desktop-computer

I was using my PC when it disconnected from the internet. Other devices were still connected so I figured the issue must be with my PC, closed my programs and then tried to restarted my PC.

This is when it blue screened with a DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE error. Once the blue screen reached 100% it hung for a good five minutes before I decided to try a hard reset and now it's stuck on the loading wheel and won't boot up again. I'm scared to try another restart but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: use Linux Live CD/DVD and get the dmp files from Windows\Minidump and share them via Cloud service. maybe this helps use to see which issue you have.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your system boots up but Windows doesn't load. Please don't forget to backup/save your data if necessary you can connect your storage to another machine. 
With the little info provided, I am guessing you had a power handling issues with your PC (Laptop right?) network module driver (Wifi right?) which is very popular on Windows 10 unfortunately. If that's the case, I doubt your computer is hurt. Just try to boot into safe mode and see if your PC works with WiFi module off. Then you can reinstall the driver and use the most stable version for your setup. Please note that the cause of this issue might be the last driver/configuration change you were applying to your system so don't forget to check other possibilities or use system restore to see if at an earlier set up your system would work healthier.

Ps: Next time please be ready to take a photo of the blue screen and note the exact reason provided by windows in smaller font.

You can find more information on this issue here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/driverpowerstatefailure/a51a93d7-8f95-42e0-bfd8-6fbc5110319c?auth=1

And here:
https://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/blue-screen-errors/microsoft-corporation/windows-operating-system/bug-check-0x9f-driver-power-state-failure/